# Line graph not showing with barchart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I'm having difficulty getting this code to generate a bar chart with a line chart on top of it when I filter my dataframe down to the last 7 dates. Currently, I can run each graph individually and they work fine but when I run them both together it gives me the bar chart with no line chart. How do I correct this?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

# CSV's from report server. Change name accordingly.
quotes = pd.read_csv("PO25474.csv")
sales = pd.read_csv("SO.csv", encoding ='Latin-1')

today = pd.datetime.today().date()
selected_date = pd.date_range(today - pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d'), today, freq='D')


#Apply to any price columns
def convert_currency(val):
"""
Convert the string number value to a float
 - Remove $
 - Remove commas
 - Convert to float type
"""
new_val = val.replace(',','')
return float(new_val)

#Convert dates and price column data types.
quotes["ENTRY_DATE"] = quotes["ENTRY_DATE"].astype("datetime64")
quotes["EXT_PRICE"] = quotes['EXT_PRICE'].apply(convert_currency)

df_selected = quotes[quotes["ENTRY_DATE"].isin(selected_date)]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

ax = (df_selected.groupby(['ENTRY_DATE'])['QTY'].sum().plot(kind="bar", 
use_index='index'))
ax.set_xlabel("Quotes")
ax.set_ylabel("Total")
ax.set_title("PO25474")

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = (df_selected.groupby([df_selected['ENTRY_DATE'].dt.day])['EXT_PRICE'].sum().plot(kind='line', marker='o', color='k'))

plt.show()
```

*Edit*
When I run this dataframe with no date restriction it runs fine. Now that I've changed it to the last seven days the line chart won't show up.

Comment: @DizietAsahi that question doesn't solve my problem at all. The graphs run fine individually and unrestricted but when I restrict by the last dates it gives up.

Comment: Is it possible to create a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidG I'm relatively inexperienced with python. This is as minimal as I've been able to get it. Would the output graph help?